# How to delete the deployment history of a repository in GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-pages

How to delete the deployment history of a repository in GitHub to show only the active?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. On GitHub.com, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click Settings.
3. In the left sidebar, click Environments.
4. Next to the environment that you want to delete, click delete. Click I understand, delete this environment.

Comment: As of the time of this comment, there doesn't appear to be any "Environments" option in the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a github action to automatically delete deployments on the next commit ([from this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788012/delete-github-repository-deployment-history/74771542#74771542)).

For example, if there is a deployment to github-pages, you can add the following entry to the workflow

```
jobs:
  cleanup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all

    steps:
      - name:  Delete deployment
        uses: strumwolf/delete-deployment-environment@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          environment: github-pages
          onlyRemoveDeployments: true
```

This action will delete all existing deployments on the specified environment (`github-pages`)

This action should be run before the deploy, so that there will be no record of the deploy in the environment, and the deploy that will run afterwards will create only 1 record.

To make sure that the deploy runs after cleaning, you can add it to your deploy process:

```
needs: cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/delete-deployment-environment) for this on the github market place -
and this is the [repo](https://github.com/strumwolf/delete-deployment-environment) where it originally lives.

The codebase is too large to have a minimal viable solution here. But following the others answer and just setting up a new repo, is probably a more efficient way to go for.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple. You need to delete the github repository and create it again under the same name. Next, do a push. All commit dates will be saved and all deployment history will be deleted.

Comment: I don't want to do this after every update. Thank you for your reply!